# Create a oracle db trigger using thin jdbc driver

Tags: java, sql, oracle, triggers, ora-00900

currently I setting up a test environment for an application. I'm using jUnit and Spring in my test environment. Before a test execution I want to set up a database test environment state. I already has written the SQL scripts (schema and data) and they runs fine in Oracles SQLDeveloper. As I tried to execute them by using the oracle thin jdbc driver, the execution fails. It looks like that the thin driver doesn't like create trigger statements.

I read that I have to use an oci driver instead of thin driver. The problem with the oci driver is that it is not platform independent and it takes time to set it up.

Example of my code:

```
CREATE TABLE "USER"
  (
    USER_ID          NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
    CREATOR_USER_FK  NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (USER_ID)
  );
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_USER START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;
CREATE TRIGGER "USER_ID_SEQ_INC" BEFORE
  INSERT ON "USER" FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  SELECT SEQ_USER.nextval
  INTO :new.USER_ID
  FROM DUAL;
END;
```

If I execute the the trigger statement the execution fails, but I looks like that the first part of the query (CREATE TRIGGER "USER_ID_SEQ_INC" ... "USER" ... BEGIN ... FROM DUAL;) is executed successfully, but the trigger seems to be corrupt if I try to use it. The execution fail error comes with the second part of the statement END; "ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement".

Do anyone know a solution for that problem? I just want to create a trigger with platform independent thin jdbc driver.

Cheers!

Kevin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you guys for your answers, It works fine now. The reason was a syntax mistake or the interpretation of my SQL code file with Spring Framefork. When I execute the statements directly by using the execute method of jdbc it works, when I use the Spring functionality for script execution the execution fails. With oracle sql code it seems to be tricky, because if I use hsqldb sql code it works fine.

test-condext.xml:

```
...
<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource"
    ignore-failures="DROPS" enabled="${jdbc.enableSqlScripts}">
    <jdbc:script location="${jdbc.initLocation}" />
    <jdbc:script location="${jdbc.dataLocation}" />
</jdbc:initialize-database>
...
```

---

schema.sql:

```
DROP SEQUENCE SEQ_USER;
DROP TABLE "USER" CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
PURGE TABLE "USER";
CREATE TABLE "USER"
  (
    USER_ID          NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
    CREATOR_USER_FK  NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (USER_ID)
  );
ALTER TABLE "USER" ADD CONSTRAINT FK_USER_CUSER FOREIGN KEY (CREATOR_USER_FK) REFERENCES "USER" (USER_ID);
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_USER START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;
CREATE TRIGGER "USER_ID_SEQ_INC" BEFORE
  INSERT ON "USER" FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN (new.USER_ID IS NULL)
BEGIN
  SELECT SEQ_USER.nextval
  INTO :new.USER_ID
  FROM DUAL;
END;
/
ALTER TRIGGER "USER_ID_SEQ_INC" ENABLE;
```

---

This works fine! Its important to remove `;` at the end of statements excepts the trigger statement!!!

```
@Before
public void executeSomeSql() {
    Connection c;
    try {
        c = dataSource.getConnection();
        c.createStatement()
                .execute("CREATE TABLE \"USER\" (USER_ID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL, CREATOR_USER_FK NUMBER(10) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (USER_ID))");
        c.createStatement()
                .execute("CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_USER START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1");
        c.createStatement()
                .execute("CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER \"USER_ID_SEQ_INC\" BEFORE INSERT ON \"USER\" FOR EACH ROW WHEN (new.USER_ID IS NULL) BEGIN SELECT SEQ_USER.nextval INTO :new.USER_ID FROM DUAL; END;");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.debug(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating triggers works with any type of JDBC driver; there must be something wrong with the SQL syntax -- which is odd because Oracle should report that when you run the `CREATE TRIGGER` (not when you use it the first time).

Since you use `BEGIN ... END;` make sure that you really have a `;` after `END` in the SQL which you send to the DB.

If that isn't the cause, [check this article](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/AutoNumber.php).

Comment: Thank you Aaron for your answer, and the article. Unfortunately it is not the semicolon at the statement :(

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a old post but here's my answer.

By default, Spring "initialize-database" instruction split the specified script by using the semicolon character : ";".

In a trigger, there often is a semicolon inside the trigger, thus the queries are badly splitted and executed.

The solution is to use another split character ("|" for example) like this :

```
<jdbc:initialize-database>
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:myscript.sql" separator="|"/>
</jdbc:initialize-database>
```